# How to Refactor this if condition

Tags: c#, refactoring

Is there a better way to refactor this if condition? or just leave it alone?

```
if (buttonindex == 1 || buttonindex == 4 || buttonindex == 10 || buttonindex == 12 || buttonindex == 14 || buttonindex == 15 || buttonindex == 17|| buttonindex == 18) 
{
 dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare an array with the valid indexes like

`int[] validIndexes = new int[] { 1, 4, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18 };`

And then use it like this

```
if (validIndexes.Contains(buttonindex))
{
    dosomething();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps also include the namespace where `.Contains()` is found.

Comment: That namespace would be  `System.Linq` , I didn't mention it because it is included by default

Comment: That depends. If you e.g. have a console app using .NET 5, it is _not_ included by default.

Comment: It's only included by default for .NET Framework applications. In .NET 6, even System isn't included by default. And that only considers Visual Studio templates. Rider, VSCode, etc. might behave differently.

Comment: Well I didn't know that, only working with .NET Framework for the last months, good to know